# Arithmetic Interface Abstractions

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I was thinking about making an arithmetic abstract class, but I have a couple of concerns and so I've decided to seek an opinion from StackOverflow.

An arithmetic abstract class would define (1) arithmetic operators, including scalar multiplication and division, (2) boolean comparisons, without implying an order (3) the commutator, anti-commutator and associator (4) define values for one and zero and (5) prove assertions about the numeric structure's algebra.

- Is there an existing abstract class for this?
- Are there any better explanations on the web for how type_trait works, particularly in regard to is_arithmetic?

Thanks

Comment: What would an arithmetic abstract class do?

Comment: It will define (1) arithmetic operators, including scalar multiplication and division, (2) boolean comparisons, without implying an order (3) the commutator, anti-commutator and associator (4) define values for one and zero and (5) prove assertions about the numeric structure's algebra.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to work with types that abstract arithmetic _itself_ for like set theory and such?  I really don't understand what you're looking for here.  Maybe a brief, incomplete example?

Comment: lol... int... I think this mostly falls under section (5) and I would be looking at proximity, rather than a traditional order for the abstraction.

Comment: My concern is that I'm going to get branched types that are split at the root.

Comment: Step 1 would be to clarify what you mean by an arithmetic class, so that we can understand why `int` isn't good enough.

Comment: Usually, `int` is good enough and usually both the commutator and associator are zero.  I'm looking for unusual mathematical properties.

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. What better explanation do you need? Type traits are generally implemented via template specialization, and the meaning of "arithmetic type" is "integer or floating point type".

Comment: Is C# any better about this, without sacrificing too much in the way of speed?

Comment: @JustKevin: I wouldn't know. Ask someone who knows C#.